# How to use RGB keyboard on linux?

Tags: keyboard, startup, hardware, input-devices

I've recently installed Ubuntu on my computer. When Ubuntu starts, my RGB keyboard light is **off**!!

Can you help me get the light to work with Ubuntu?

Comment: We can't help you without knowing the hardware in question.

Comment: And the software version. 20.10 and 21.04 deal with certain devices differently, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal, this can be done via the applications UI in the bottom left. ctrl+T might also work.

Then you will want to type in: man xset

This is the manual for xset. If you are new this sort of thing it might come over as intimidating, but don't worry.

If you scroll down a little you will find there to be a tab for 'led'.
Read it. .......... You done? Great!

To return to the command line press: q

Okay, so in your case the command 'xset led' should work, try it!